# Duplicating a wordpress navigation menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some courses of html, php, css, javascript and MySql. Now I decided to continue learning from the practice while I build a Wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I'm trying to learn how to overlay two different font families in the same div. I mean something like this:

[image]

I discover that it's something possible to do with css using `content: attr(data-title);`

For example:

```
.button {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,800" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button" data-title="ABC">ABC</a>
```

Now my big problem is that I'm working with Wordpress and the php is a little more complex. What I would like to do is to have two different fonts for each menu item. For example:

[image]

This is the code php of my menu:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                ) );
            ?>
        </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this is the css:

```
.main-navigation {
    font-family: pcablack;
    font-size: 30px;
     word-spacing: -5px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

I tried to make this but it doesn't work as I expect. It seems that maybe there is a syntax problem:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>"

        data-title= '

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>'
        >

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                ) );
            ?>
        </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

then the css:

```
.main-navigation {
    font-family: pcablack;
    font-size: 30px;
     word-spacing: -5px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-navigation:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    font-family: pcabold;
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
     word-spacing: -5px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1100;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

It doesn't work. It only shows me console errors. Do you have some recommendation?

Maybe there is an easiest way to duplicate the font of a menu item and overlay it?

Other problem is that my menu is an accordion menu. So if I open a section of one of the menus that I duplicate the other menu should be automatically open too.

Comment: The title of this question is quite misleading. I thought you wanted to simply duplicate a menu. Perhaps a title more descriptive of the fact you're trying to create a duplicate text overlay with 2 separate fonts would be better. That being said I feel like, rather than output the entire menu twice, you would be better off simply duplicating the entries using javascript instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @WilliamPatton . Do you have some suggestion about how can I duplicate the entries using javascript? I'm learning and there are things  that are news for me.

Comment: The problem is that the menu is an accordion menu so if I open an item in one of the two menus the other should be open automatically too

Comment: Opening a menu is as simple as assigning it a class and setting display property to something else than _none_. Or just using `docuemnt.getElementBySomeMethod().style.display = "something besides none";`. Personally I prefer the class method since it's easily reusable.

Comment: @Beneris provided an answer that shows some JavaScript for you to try use. You can include it in your header to try see if it works. You may need to adjust the class names and change the '$' in the javascript to `jQuery`. Also some additional reading regarding best practices for adding Javascript in WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, you doing this wrong.

You need copy only menu items titles to data attribute. SO for example:

```js
$('.main-menu ul a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  $(this).attr('data-title', text);
});
```

```css
.main-menu li a {
  position:relative;
   font-family: "Arial Black";
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-menu li a:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position:absolute;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    display:block;
  font-size: 14px;
    z-index:1;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-menu">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Why</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: But how can I use that javascript in Wordpress? I hold use it in the header.php?

Comment: In a WordPress environment javascript here will fail as jQuery is included by WordPress in No Conflict mode (`jQuery.noConflict();`) and so the shorthand `$` doesn't work to reference it. Needs to use the full reference `jQuery` instead.

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPatton yo are amazing!

Comment: Thank you @Beneris you are amazing!